# Regular expression for finding more than 4 consecutive repeating characters in a string

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I want to find out more than 4 consecutive repeating characters within a string. e.g. `(string is lowercased)`

```
bbaaaaa ---> yes (5 consecutive a's)
bbaa   ---> no
aabbbbbccdddddee ---> yes (5 consecutive b's)
```

One possible solution is to loop over `a` to `z` and use `character{4,}` where `character` can be anyone from `a` to `z`.

Is there any one liner for it?

I apologize if its duplicate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import re
[i for i,j in re.findall(r"((.)\2{3,})",test_str)]
```

This should do it for you.

Output:

```
['aaaaa', 'bbbbb', 'ddddd']
```

Comment: i got it..actually it was just `yes` or `no`..so we can also use `re.search(r'([a-z])\1{4}', "bbaaaaa")`

Comment: @rock321987 ohh i thought you wanted the content as well.Yes you can then use `search`

Comment: @rock321987 use `re.search(r'([a-z])\1{3,}` to get more than `4` strings.What you are proposing would get only string of length `5`.

Comment: Can any one explain this answer?

Comment: @keramat it's capturing a character and then says the same character captured should 3 or more

Comment: Thanks @vks, what is the role of \2? and why we need two capturing group?

Comment: @keramat \1 is the bigger capture group..\2 is the character which is repeating...we need both as we want return the result with not just 'a' but 'aaaaa'